# Can matplotlib.pyplot.plot color code a curve pointwise

Tags: matplotlib

Here is an example from matplotlib, where pyplot.plot is used and a curve is **piecewise** color coded.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

upper = 0.77
lower = -0.77

supper = np.ma.masked_where(s < upper, s)
slower = np.ma.masked_where(s > lower, s)
smiddle = np.ma.masked_where((s < lower) | (s > upper), s)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, smiddle, t, slower, t, supper)
plt.show()
```

[image]

My question is: Can matplotlib.pyplot.plot color code a curve also **pointwise** (using any color map). I know that I could use matplotlib.pyplot.scatter instead to do that.

Comment: What do you mean pointwise? As in plot different points in different colours? `.plot()` can't do this, but why would you want it to, when you have `.scatter()`? Perhaps you're better off describing _why_ you want to do this?

Answer (score -1):

No, it can't. See [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html). As you say, `use plt.scatter()` for this.

You could call it for every point in your dataset using a different marker format for each, but that would be insanity, because it would effectively call `.plot()` for every point it plots, which is very wasteful when `.scatter()` exists.

If you insist though:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 1000
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n)
y = np.sin(x)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('hsv')
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=y.min(), vmax=y.max())

for i in range(n):
    plt.plot(x[i], y[i], marker='.', markersize=25, c=cmap(norm(y[i])))
plt.show()
```

[image: Scatter with .plot()]

Comment: The ist not an insanity. See here: https://imgur.com/gallery/wuoksFV

Comment: That example uses `.scatter()`, which is exactly what I am suggesting in my answer. Why do you think calling `.plot()` for every point in your dataset makes sense instead of calling `.scatter()` once? It would be terrible for performance and completely unnecessary when `.scatter()` exists.